# Creating new class by program API classes in C#(not recognized as program's model objects )

Tags: c#

I'm working with a program's API in C# (Tekla Structures). I created a new class with the program's default classes in the namespace and then in the main program I created an object of it.

It works fine - the object will create in the program. But then when I want to do another function like cutting on this object that I created it won't work and the error message is here:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'test_class.Form1.CreateBeam' to
> 'Tekla.Structures.Model.ModelPbject'

Code:

```
namespace test_class
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Point Point1 = new Point(0, 0, 0);
            Point Point2 = new Point(3000, 0, 0);
            CreateBeam MyBeam = new CreateBeam();
            MyBeam.BeamStartPointEndPoint(Point1, Point2);

            Fitting EndFit_1 = new Fitting();
            EndFit_1.Plane = new Plane();
            EndFit_1.Plane.Origin = new Point(100, 0, 0);
            EndFit_1.Plane.AxisX = new Vector(500, 0, 0);
            EndFit_1.Plane.AxisY = new Vector(0, -500, 0);
            EndFit_1.Father = MyBeam;

        }

       //new Class

        public class CreateBeam
        {
            public void BeamStartPointEndPoint(Point Point1, Point Point2)
            {
                Beam MyBeam = new Beam();
                MyBeam.StartPoint = Point1;
                MyBeam.EndPoint = Point2;
                MyBeam.Finish = "PAINT";
                MyBeam.Profile.ProfileString = "PL10*200";
                MyBeam.Insert();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

The error occurs at this line:

```
EndFit_1.Father = MyBeam;
```

Documentation: https://developer.tekla.com/tekla-structures/api/14/14118

Does anyone know what should I do?

Comment: Please show us all relevant code.

Comment: Instead of describing your code, actually post it here so we can see it. The question as it stands cannot be answered by anyone.

Comment: It looks like somewhere, somehow, you tried to assign an object of one type (a `CreateBeam` object) to a variable which can only hold a different type of object (it can hold `ModelProject` objects). Without seeing the precise code you used, it's difficult to give you any advice other than "you can't do that, the types must match". If you'd like advice on how you might best resolve it, please provide a [mre] of your issue - i.e. enough code that it would produce the error if used in a C# program. Your description by itself is too vague and ambiguous for us to know precisely what has happened.

Comment: Thanks for the update. So...which line exactly causes the error? You didn't clarify that. Is it perhaps `EndFit_1.Father = MyBeam;`, at a guess? If so then it would mean that the `Father` property can only hold objects which are of the type `ModelProject`. It's unclear why you would expect it to be able to hold a `CreateBeam`, or indeed what you're intending to achieve by assigning it there.

Comment: Is there any documentation you can give us a link to which documents the `Fitting` class? Or the source code of it?

Comment: Yes the Problem is at " EndFit_1.Father = MyBeam;"

Comment: Ok friends let me explain a bit. i'm not professional so sorry for some mistakes. Fitting is a class of the Software's (Tekla structures) API. I Created a Beam that is MyBeam and i want to do a Fitting (Like Cutting) on this Beam. problem is here bcs the beam I created by my new class is not ModelObject.

Comment: https://developer.tekla.com/tekla-structures/api/14/14118

Comment: @ADyson thanks for replying , I tagged a link that is reference for Fitting Class.

Comment: Thanks. So as I suspected, https://developer.tekla.com/tekla-structures/api/14/13757 notes that the Father property has a type of `ModelObject`. It can accept objects of that type, or any type which inherits from it. But `CreateBeam` is obviously not `ModelObject` and it also doesn't inherit from it. So it's not clear why you tried to assign a `CreateBeam` object to that property. What are you expecting will happen? We can identify the problem now, but we cannot really suggest a fix because your intent and goal is not known to us.

Comment: (P.S. To use an analogy, your problem is similar to having a lock which requires a certain type of key to unlock it. However, instead of providing an appropriate key, you tried to unlock it with a tomato. i.e. it appears to make no sense and there's no obvious solution other than to say "use a key instead".)

Comment: @ADyson  thanks. First of all i create a new class to Creating for example Beam to avoid repeating long lines in my program. the new class is CreateBeam (in this class i used 'Beam' class that is a class of Tekla software) it works itself I mean the Beam will Create in software but it seems bcs i created a new class it wont be a Tekla 'ModelObject ' anymore. I Wrote the Error message in question . i want to know Is there any problem with the class i created or what should i do to solve it. by this code i wrote i can only create the Beam and i wont be able to cut it or other functions.

Comment: `(in this class i used 'Beam' class that is a class of Tekla software`...ok but you didn't use that `Beam` instance to set as the Father property. You need to assign the Beam you created to the Father property, not the CreateBeam wrapper.

Comment: One way would be to return the Beam from your method and then use it. e.g. `public Beam BeamStartPointEndPoint(Point Point1, Point Point2)
            {` .... `return MyBeam; }`. And then `Beam beam = MyBeam.BeamStartPointEndPoint(Point1, Point2);` ... `EndFit_1.Father = beam;`. Since `Beam` inherits from `ModelObject` (as per https://developer.tekla.com/tekla-structures/api/14/13623) I'd expect that to work.

Comment: @ADyson thanks for replying. the code of class should be like this?

Comment: public class CreateBeam
    {

        public Beam BeamStartPointEndPoint(Point Point1, Point Point2)
        {

            Beam MyBeam = new Beam();
            MyBeam.StartPoint = Point1;
            MyBeam.EndPoint = Point2;
            MyBeam.Finish = "PAINT";
            MyBeam.Profile.ProfileString = "PL10*200";
            MyBeam.Insert();

            return MyBeam;
        }

    }

Comment: No. I showed you what to do already. You can't return from a constructor. I'm not sure why you changed that from the method you had before, and which I showed you how to amend in my example

Comment: @ADyson thank you so much.  Yes. it works Fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing an answer now the question is re-opened, based on the comments above.

https://developer.tekla.com/tekla-structures/api/14/13757 notes that the `Father` property has a type of `ModelObject`. It can accept objects of that type, or any type which inherits from it. But `CreateBeam` is obviously not `ModelObject` and it also doesn't inherit from it.

Within the class you're creating a `Beam` object. As per https://developer.tekla.com/tekla-structures/api/14/13623 `Beam` *does* inherit from `ModelObject` so it looks like that's what you really need to assign to `Father`.

At the moment your object exists only within that `BeamStartPointEndPoint` method. So to make it work, one approach is to return the `Beam` object from the method so you can assign it later on.

For example:

```
    public class CreateBeam
    {
        public Beam BeamStartPointEndPoint(Point Point1, Point Point2)
        {
            Beam MyBeam = new Beam();
            MyBeam.StartPoint = Point1;
            MyBeam.EndPoint = Point2;
            MyBeam.Finish = "PAINT";
            MyBeam.Profile.ProfileString = "PL10*200";
            MyBeam.Insert();
            return MyBeam;
        }
    }
```

and then:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Point Point1 = new Point(0, 0, 0);
        Point Point2 = new Point(3000, 0, 0);
        CreateBeam MyBeam = new CreateBeam();
        Beam beam = MyBeam.BeamStartPointEndPoint(Point1, Point2);

        Fitting EndFit_1 = new Fitting();
        EndFit_1.Plane = new Plane();
        EndFit_1.Plane.Origin = new Point(100, 0, 0);
        EndFit_1.Plane.AxisX = new Vector(500, 0, 0);
        EndFit_1.Plane.AxisY = new Vector(0, -500, 0);
        EndFit_1.Father = beam;
    }
```